# Authenticate users using email verification link in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have just started exploring Keycloak, so not having much idea about it. I am able to send verification link to the email id of the user. On click of verification link present in the email, it is getting verified successfully.

However, the user is redirected to the login page on successful verification. I want to know whether it is possible to embed some kind of tokens/security info in validation link which will automatically let the user sign in on click of verification link?

Comment: What would happen if the email went to the wrong person?

Comment: If email is sent to wrong email id, they will neither be able to verify nor login. I did not understand what this question is to do with email getting sent to wrong person.

Comment: This feature is not available in keycloak,  similar feature request  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-1942

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to do email verification? Do you maybe have code example?